# the application precedence for the infix form for multiple expressions

Tags: haskell

Say I have this expression:

```
instance FromRow MyData where
  fromRow =  MyData <$> field <*> field <*> field
```

I can't undertand the application precedence because everything is written in the infix form. Can you help me? Is this correct?

```
fromRow =  MyData (1) <$> (2) field  (3) <*>  (4) field  (5) <*>  (6) field
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `<$>` and `<*>` are left-associative, so your numbering is correct. You could also write it using parentheses like this:

```haskell
(((MyData <$> field) <*> field) <*> field)
```

Comment: how do you know that are left-associative?

Comment: You can always go to [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%24%3E) and type in the function (e.g. `<$>`). Then you can look at the package and right by the definition of `<$>`, you'll see it listed as [`infixl 4`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-). `infixl` means left-associative, whereas `infixr` is right-associative.

Comment: In GHCi, type `:i <$>`. That will tell you its type, and where it's defined, and then `infixl 4 <$>`. The details of what that means are explained in plain language in the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#fixity).

Comment: The `4` in the fixity declaration sets its precedence in regards to other infix  operators as to which of them gets evaluated first (9 binds most tightly, down to 0, which binds the least). [See section 4.4.2 here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#nested) for a more in-depth description as well as a helpful table showing visually the fixity of a number of common operators